# behind the scenes of server download and upload

Tags: file-upload, upload, download, webserver, cloud

I always wondered how doe's server upload and download works exactly...
for example when I download a file that sits on a server at a certain speed does the server need to have high upload speed to match my download speed while serving my file?

would appreciate anyone who could offer some insight.
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is ...  Server upload speed matters ..  That is the reason, there are business plans  from service providers  in which upload speed is more than download speed.  else in normal case  upload speed is 1/3  or so of download speed

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normally in a commercial environment the upload and download speeds are the same (depends on the plan you choose). Thing to be noted is that if a server has 40 Mbps upload speed then in order to optimize the performance of the server bandwidth throttling may be used to control user's usage of bandwidth.This helps in optimized sharing of bandwidth.